# What is GLKMatrix4 in OpenGL (iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

Im new to iPhone game development, can you please explain about the GLKMatrix4 in OpenGL.
please any one help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Apple's doc:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GLkit/Reference/GLKMatrix4/Reference/reference.html)

> The GKLMatrix4 type defines a 4x4 floating-point matrix as well as
>   many mathematical operations commonly used to manipulate matrices.
>   OpenGL ES uses matrices extensively as a convenient way to represent a
>   graphical transformation between different coordinate systems. These
>   transformations include translation, scaling, rotation and projection;
>   through matrix multiplication, multiple transformations can be
>   concatenated into a single transformation matrix.
>
> The functions that manipulate GKLMatrix4 structures treat the inputs
>   as immutable, instead returning a new matrix that represent the
>   results of the operation.

Matrices in 3D programming are most commonly used for transformations: moving, rotating, scaling, etc. your objects in the 3D scene, calculate the viewport of a camera, and so on. If this sounds you somehow blur try to read some introduction to 3D programming like this one (this is specific for OpenGL ES for your convenience): http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.it/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html
Especially [Chapter 7](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.it/2009/06/opengl-es-from-ground-up-part-7_04.html) you might find useful.

Answer (score 0):

4x4 floating-point matrix as  mathematical operations used to manipulate matrices. There r Some kind of creating matrices. Read from [apple document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GLkit/Reference/GLKMatrix4/Reference/reference.html)  and [GLKMatrix4 Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKMatrix4/GLKMatrix4.pdf)